# Gitlab CI - Specifying Runner Per Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

We are currently facing a conundrum with our multi-tenant project which contains various configuration files for each of our tenants and their associated environment. Our CI/CD Pipeline is split into two parts

- An Upstream pipeline which analyses the new commit to master to
  determine which tenants/environments have been changed. This triggers
  the downstream pipeline with the correct environment variables via
  the API
- A downstream pipeline which executes scripts to deploy
  changes to the tenants' environment based on the environment variables
  passed through. This works well, however we have a Gitlab Runner per
  environment to access the customers environment. We use this to avoid
  hard-coding multiple credentials within our scripts or CI environment
  variables.

Is there a way we can trigger this downstream pipeline with the specific Gitlab Runner? Our Gitlab Runners are tagged per environment so that we can use the passed environment variables to detect which runner it should be ran on.

I’ve had a look around the Gitlab CI, specific runners and shared runners (which ours are currently) but doesn’t seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

`tags:` supports variable expansion. So, it is possible to [pass variables in the API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#pass-cicd-variables-in-the-api-call) when creating your downstream pipelines in order to control which runners are used.